# Copy and paste clipboard history selectively

Tags: gnome, clipboard, copy, paste, clipboard-manager

Is there a way (I know this is very specific but hang with me) to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to copy the last thing on your clip board and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for the thing after that and so on and so forth? I know that there are widgets and thing you can get, but I think that this would be way easier.